# Locking directories

Tags: 22.04

I recently installed Ubuntu and immediately after installing the Desktop, Music, Pictures, etc, directories got locked as shown below, anyone know why? Even with the `cd` command, it says the path was not found.

[image]

Comment: No, when I try to change permissions with chmod or chown, I get the following error:

chmod: cannot access 'Videos': Too many levels of symbolic links

chown: cannot dereference 'Videos': Too many levels of symbolic links

@graham

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx  1  9 00:31 Templates -> /home/mohammad/Templates

Comment: @muru Thanks, yes that is exactly the problem.